# Mod rewrite, for category and its pages, conflicts

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have **category.php** and it has `?slug='something'`, so that looks like this after I did some code in **.htaccess**: `www.example.com/category/football`. And it works well, BUT I need to implement page numbering so my link would be something like this: `www.example.com/category/football/page/2`. I did it also with some code in **.htaccess**, BUT it does not work.

I wrote this code in **category.php** to indicate some stuff:

```
echo "$_GET['slug']"

if(isset($_GET['page']))
   echo $_GET['page']
```

When I go to `www.example.com/category/football` it's all ok, I get "**fudbal**" message from `echo $_GET['slug']`

BUT when I go to `www.example.com/category/football/page/2` it's NOT ok, I get "**fudbal/page/2**" (I supose it echoes like it's all slug) from `echo $_GET['slug']` and `$_GET['page']` does not give anything.

Here is my **.htaccess**:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ themes/tema_2/category.php?slug=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/page/(\d+)/?$ themes/tema_2/category.php?slug=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Try it here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
I got error:

> This rule was met, the new url is http://www.example.com/themes/tema_2/category.php?slug=fudbal/page/2
>   The tests are stopped because the L in your RewriteRule options

Comment: Remove the "/" from pattern of your first rule.

Comment: Thanks, it is better, but still does not echoes "$_GET['page']"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ themes/tema_2/category.php?slug=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/page/(\d+)/?$ themes/tema_2/category.php?slug=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: When I do "echo $_GET['page']"... does not work... I need that page to store in my variable